# Maximum call stack size exceeded when try to install babel cli

Tags: node.js, github, babeljs

I am engaging with an node project. I using github as the version controller as well as visual studio code as the text editor. 
for install the

- babel-cli
- babel-preset-env

packagers , I entered follow command

`npm install -D babel-cli babel-preset-env nodemon`

Then terminal showed this error.

```
PS C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\MEANBack> npm install -D babel-cli babel-preset-env nodemon
npm WARN MEANBack@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN MEANBack@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ruwan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-11T08_21_08_741Z-debug.log
```

Then I tried to Discard the all changes by the visual studio. It not success. What should i do for this.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough ram available ?

Comment: my ram is 4GB. Is it not enough for this.

Comment: Yup, that might be a issue. How big is your project ?

Comment: It is very small project. just only a CRUD

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in a very different environment. I was able to get around it with `yarn global add babel-cli`.

I'm building a Docker image based on `ubuntu:14.04` (that's April 2014), with Docker `18.06.3~se~3-0~ubuntu` (2019) and node 14.17.5 (released this week in 2021). This is a bizarre combination of old and new. My Docker engine has 10GB of RAM and 4 CPUs assigned, so resources shouldn't be an issue.

My Dockerfile included this command:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION=14.17.5
RUN curl -SL "http://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" | \
    tar xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 && \
    npm install -g yarn@1.0.2 babel-cli
```

resulting in a fun set of errors:

```
#11 5.898 npm WARN deprecated yarn@1.0.2: It is recommended to install Yarn using the native installation method for your environment. See https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
#11 6.208 /usr/local/bin/yarn -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
#11 6.208 /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
#11 6.217 + yarn@1.0.2
#11 6.217 added 1 package in 1.339s
#11 10.21 npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
#11 12.49 npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
#11 15.98 npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
#11 23.90 npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
#11 23.91 npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
#11 32.48 /usr/local/bin/babel -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js
#11 32.48 /usr/local/bin/babel-doctor -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-doctor.js
#11 32.48 /usr/local/bin/babel-external-helpers -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-external-helpers.js
#11 32.48 /usr/local/bin/babel-node -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js
#11 32.62 
#11 32.62 > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/core-js
#11 32.62 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
#11 32.62 
#11 33.62 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
#11 33.62 npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
#11 33.62 
#11 33.76 npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
#11 33.87 
#11 33.87 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#11 33.87 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-13T12_31_19_942Z-debug.log
```

including the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error in what appears to be the install stage.

My fix was to use `yarn` to install the package:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION=14.17.5
RUN curl -SL "http://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" | \
    tar xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 && \
    npm install -g yarn@1.0.2 && \
    yarn global add babel-cli
```

This allowed installation to continue and `babel` to be available globally.